# Two Way Sync Logic

Tags: php, csv, logic

I have a CSV file with information about our inventory that gets changed locally and then uploaded to my web server at night. The website also has a copy of the inventory information in its MySQL database that might have also changed.

What I want to accomplish is a two-way sync between in the inventory information in the database and the CSV file that's uploaded. Parsing the CSV and extracting the info from the database isn't a problem, but now that I have the two sets of data, I'm struggling to figure out how to sync them.

If a record is different between the CSV and database, how do I know which one to use? I really don't want to resort to having my users time stamp every change they make on the CSV. Is there some way I can tell which information is more current?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. Just in case you're wondering, I tagged this question PHP because that's the language I'll be using to accomplish the synching.

Comment: Without a timestamp you basically cannot who edited first. So there will not be a way to determine which is the latest.

Comment: I was afraid of that. How do version control systems handle this? Could I do something involving keeping 2 copies of the CSV on the server and comparing them first before I compared it to the database?

Comment: For version controls. If the data is conflicted, it ask the user to resolve the conflict.

Comment: If it was a database to database sync, you could always add a timestamp. But for csv , there is no way to tell which version is edited first. Why not just allow the user to update the data directly instead of using a csv.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I was just asking about version control systems because 99% of the time I use them, I don't have to manually merge changes. It just "knows" which version to use. To answer your other question, I might wind up having users just update the data directly given how much of a pain this is proving to be. For now though, I think I've hacked together a simple/dirty system to automatically time stamp changes to the CSV via Excel, so if you want to propose that as a solution, I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you very much for all of your help.

Comment: The reason you have not encountered any conflict is because no one has updated the same chunk of file at the same time. :)

Comment: I have posted an extended version of my suggestion below... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a time stamp field. And have an application that updates the timestamp overtime the record changes.

I have a similar app done before where multiple sites sync records up and down based on 3 time stamp. One to track when the record was last updated. One to track when the record was deleted. And one to track when the changes was copied to this pc.

Then on every pc, i also track when was the last time the records was.synchronized with each other pc.

This way, the latest record can always be propogated to all the pc.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As a side question, my plan right now is to just loop through each copy of the inventory and check it against the other making changes based on the time stamps. Is there a faster way you know of?

Comment: But how are the users keeping their copy of the spreadsheet updated?

Comment: I have a cron job that uploads the CSV to the server and then downloads the updated CSV after the server has finished synching it.

Comment: So if mote than one copy of the file has changes in the same location? How will it handle that?

Comment: There is only 1 copy of the file at each location. All users modify the same Excel file over the local network. Any changes they make are automatically exported to a CSV file that is uploaded for synchronization with the website. The more I'm thinking about this though, the more it is making sense for me to just abandon the CSV/Excel file and make everyone transition to using the database only, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a versioning issue. A simple solution would be to compare all 'lines' or 'records' (if you have unique identifiers) and ask the user to pick the right values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't mind having users pick the right value when there are conflicts, but I would like to avoid having user intervention for every change.

Comment: Some changes you might be able to merge automatically because you can make assumptions about which party changes what fields, this will be up to you to. This is very generic problem so I can't really give an code samples. If you have any specific questions I can answer them.